# Which code should I use to inform me of updates on websites?

Tags: programming-languages

I don't know if this is the correct place to ask this question but I'll ask it here anyway.

I don't know much about programming (I only ever learned MATLAB!) but I wonder if there is a simple way to write a code to check a website every x minutes, say, to see if a certain thing changes and notify me when it does?

I hope this question is not too vague!

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: I have computer running Windows and one running Ubuntu.

Comment: Don't do that too often, i.e. make `x` be at least 20 minutes. If too many people are doing that, the website is crushed by useless requests.

Comment: What is the website that you want to check periodically?

Comment: Thanks for your answer to my question. I will look into it. There are a few websites but the main use for me is to check when tickets are available for certain events. How do I find out if this is allowed?

Comment: Do you really need to code it? if you can use a service, I like https://www.changedetection.com/  which will send you an email when the page changes

Comment: That website seems quite useful for many cases, thanks. However, sometimes I only want to be informed when one specific number (indicating the number of people attending a specific event) on the page changes.

Answer (score 3):

It is too vague. But you basically need the following things, and glue them together:

- A thing that downloads the webpage and saves it to your computer
- A thing that compares it to the version you downloaded before this one
- A thing that notifies you about the comparison if a difference was found
- A thing that runs this whole contraption every x minutes

For the last one, if you are on Linux, then `cron` is good for running something every x minutes. The rest can be done with many different languages, like Python, but I'm not going to write it all out.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down. Maybe I should learn some Python. Is there a specific part of Python to learn? Sorry that I am such a noob with this!

Answer (score 1):

If you know MATLAB, then this should be the right way for you:

1. Get the page: [webread](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html)
2. Search the page for the HTML pattern containing your data: [strfind](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html)
3. Extract the data
4. Compare the data to the last one recorded
5. If changed, notify, else wait until timer runs out and re-run the process

Answer (score 0):

First tell us your operating system. :) You could use all languages. You have to read the html sourcecode of a website (better only the body). Be careful if there are current timestamp and so on.

Another solution would be (if supported) reading the RSS feed.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the question to answer you. Do you know of any good references to learn this sort of thing?

Comment: I would use AutoIT with INet.au3 if you have not much experience. `#include <INet.au3>
_INetGetSource ( $s_URL )`

Answer (score 0):

To complete on [RemcoGerlich answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/269310/40065) from a Linux perspective:

- download a page using a command like `wget` or `curl` or a library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (which has many wrapping, including for Python, Guile, etc...)
- compare two files with `diff` or `cmp` (or code the simple loop reading them and comparing byte by byte)
- to notify you about changes: you could send email (e.g. programmatically with [vmime](http://www.vmime.org/), or `popen` a `mail` or `sendmail` command, or code a `mail`command with a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)....); you could also be notified on the desktop e.g. with [notify-send](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1411620)
- to do something periodically, a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry.

As I commented, it could be a bad idea (so don't run that too often, at most every 30 minutes to avoid crushing the website). You might be interested by [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS). And doing that automatically might be against the rules of the website! And it might not work if the website is using cookies or sessions, etc...

BTW, some sites offer a so-called [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API) which could be useful, e.g. because they are providing the info perhaps in [JSON](http://json.org/) format. Read also about [web services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) & [Web Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) & [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) & [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)